# Display data in tree structure

Tags: javascript

I want to display data in tree strucure using Javascript. The data should be read from xml file. These data should be be displayed in tree structure. and i need to keep track of the level numbers also.Please help me out.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

[Simplistic,do it yourself, no third party libraries solution.](http://www.codetoad.com/xml_javascript_data.asp)

[jsTree jQuery plugin. Pretty powerful. Demos and source included.](https://github.com/vakata/jstree)

Comment: I realize this is a few years old, but it doesn't seem that jstree supports XML anymore (if it did originally).